# Securing Wordpress WP-Content media

Tags: wordpress, security

I'm trying to help a friend out with his website.  Neither one of us are website building experts so I'm hoping for a dummies guide kind of help.

He has built a website using Wordpress but we've noticed that there is a URL that is accessible which contains the URL for uploaded files which are supposed to be premium paid for files (typically PDF and Excel files).  The URL/folder is https://[website]/wp-json/wp/v2/media

How do we change it so these uploaded files aren't see?

Thanks in advance.

Unsure what to try but not expecting the content URLs to be visible to anyone.

Comment: Are you selling them with WooCommerce?

Comment: I'm unsure, how would I know this?

Comment: I mean if your friend built the site then he should know... But I'm asking because if you upload digital products from the product admin in WC then it automatically puts them in a protected folder, but if you upload them via the media library they are public. So if you're using WC then the answer is to just delete them and re-upload them from the product admin.

Comment: Ah! I reckon files are being uploaded via the media library.  Ok, that should give me a hint on what do to next.  Thank you very much.